# Column break with twocolumn option

Tags: two-column, columnbreak

I'm currently creating a new document class that requires the `twocolumn` option. In that class, I've created a new environment that displays an image on the left column and text on the right one. It might look like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{image.png}
\columnbreak
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
...
```

The problem is, I can't find a way of doing such a column break. The `\columnbreak` command itself does not work since I don't work in a multicol environment, and I wasn't able to find any tricks to help me perform that column break.

Any thoughts or tips to do that? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi regu! Please could you provide a full minimal working example (that can be compiled).

Comment: Hi! Sure, I've edited my post with a working example

Comment: Okay. This is very simple. Instead of `\columnbreak` use `\newpage` (or `\clearpage`)!

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! This works perfectly!